# How can i fix this Textwidget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Why is y not output twice if you type 2 in the text field?
Thanks for help

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x450")

def copy():
    y = txt.get(1.0, END)
    print(y)
    if y == "2":
        print("Check")

txt = Text(root, width=60, height=20, font=("Arial", 12))
txt.place(x=0, y=0)

btn = Button(root, text="Copy", command=copy)
btn.place(x=250, y=400)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Entry` instead of `Text`?

Answer (score 2):

because there is a hidden `\n` here. If you change your if to `if y == "2\n":` it will print check